# How to assign random values from list to new column that doesn't exist in another column of the same row but not assign to same name

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'job_id': ['0001', '0001', '0001', '0002', '0002', '0002', '0003', '0003', '0004', '0004', '0005', '0005', '0005', '0005', '0006'],
    'user_id': ['frank', 'frank', 'frank', 'jessica', 'jessica', 'jessica', 'eric', 'eric', 'james', 'james','josh','josh','josh','josh','sam']
})

   job_id  user_id
0   0001   frank
1   0001   frank
2   0001   frank
3   0002   jessica
4   0002   jessica
5   0002   jessica
6   0003   eric
7   0003   eric
8   0004   james
9   0004   james
10  0005   josh
11  0005   josh
12  0005   josh
13  0005   josh
14  0006   sam
```

Output:

```
   job_id  user_id  validator_id
0   0001   frank    jessica
1   0001   frank    jessica
2   0001   frank    jessica
3   0002   jessica  eric
4   0002   jessica  eric
5   0002   jessica  eric
6   0003   eric     james
7   0003   eric     james
8   0004   james    sam
9   0004   james    sam
10  0005   josh     frank
11  0005   josh     frank
12  0005   josh     frank
13  0005   josh     frank
14  0006   sam      josh
```

The desired output should be above format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could use a `set` difference combined with `random.choice`:

```
import random

users = set(df['user_id'])

df['validator_id'] = (df.groupby('user_id')['user_id']
                       .transform(lambda x: random.choice(list(users.difference(x))))
                     )
```

example output:

```
   job_id  user_id validator_id
0    0001    frank          sam
1    0001    frank          sam
2    0001    frank          sam
3    0002  jessica         eric
4    0002  jessica         eric
5    0002  jessica         eric
6    0003     eric        frank
7    0003     eric        frank
8    0004    james         eric
9    0004    james         eric
10   0005     josh        james
11   0005     josh        james
12   0005     josh        james
13   0005     josh        james
14   0006      sam         eric
```

***Note** that the same validator can be selected many times, or never*

---

###### Alternatively

if you want a random **rotation**:

```
from random import shuffle
users = list(set(df['user_id']))
shuffle(users)

d = dict(zip(users, users[-1:]+users[:-1]))
# {'james': 'frank', 'josh': 'james', 'eric': 'josh',
#  'jessica': 'eric', 'sam': 'jessica', 'frank': 'sam'}

df['validator_id'] = df['user_id'].map(d)
```

output:

```
   job_id  user_id validator_id
0    0001    frank          sam
1    0001    frank          sam
2    0001    frank          sam
3    0002  jessica         eric
4    0002  jessica         eric
5    0002  jessica         eric
6    0003     eric         josh
7    0003     eric         josh
8    0004    james        frank
9    0004    james        frank
10   0005     josh        james
11   0005     josh        james
12   0005     josh        james
13   0005     josh        james
14   0006      sam      jessica
```